# Climb/Descent or vectoring in other controller's airspace without point out

Tags: regulations

I'm an ATC trainee in an ACC.

Few days ago, I handed off an aircraft to the adjacent approach control, and the app. controller made it descend and vectored while it was still in our airspace; ACC's airspace. The STAR procedure starting from the handoff point says maintain present heading and flight level. 
 It was not a dangerous situation and there was no trouble, but I'm just curious about this in terms of international regulations or recommendations.

I only found this on ICAO DOC 4444

> 4.3.3.1 When area control service and approach control service are not provided by the same air traffic control unit, responsibility for
>   controlled flights shall rest with the unit providing area control
>   service except that a unit providing approach control service shall be
>   responsible for the control of:
>
> - a) arriving aircraft that have been released to it by the ACC;
> - b) departing aircraft until such aircraft are released to the ACC.

I want to know if there are specified regulations prohibiting 'climb/descent or vectoring in other controller's airspace without point out.'

Comment: Does your facility have a Letter of Agreement (or similar type of document) that releases control to the other facility within a certain distance o your common boundary? 

This is a common practice, and such agreements should be covered in your training.